# Way to get list of Evicted pods in OpenShift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Apart from Evicted , `oc  get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed' returns Error,ContainerStatusUnknown,Terminating` as well.

How to just parse this?

```
"reason": "Evicted"
```

Will this work `oc get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.status.reason!=null) | select(.status.reason | contains("Evicted"))'`

I expect to get the list of Evicted pods only ?

Comment: Evicted Pod will get removed and the owner of the Pod (ReplicaSet, Deployment) will try to replace it with a new one. So I don't think you will be able to see evicted Pods by running `oc get pods <.....>` If the Pod is still in terminating state and not completely removed from the Cluster then running the above oc command might help you to retrieve evicted Pod details